how to fit everything into one query?
Fastapi application.
query = select(Review).options(selectinload(Review.prize)
                                   .options(selectinload(ReceivedPrize.prize)),
                                   selectinload(Review.author)).where(Review.id == review_id)
                                   
likes_query = select(
        func.count(case((ReviewLike.like == True, 1))).label("likes_count"),
        func.count(case((ReviewLike.like == False, 1))).label("dislikes_count")
    ).where(ReviewLike.review_id == review_id)
    
    
    
user_like_query = select(ReviewLike).where(
        ReviewLike.review_id == review_id,
        ReviewLike.user_id == user_id
    )
    
    
    
    models:
    
    class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = "review"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    prize_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('received_prize.id'), nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    media = Column(ARRAY(String), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.current_timestamp())

    author = relationship("User", back_populates="reviews", lazy="select")
    prize = relationship("ReceivedPrize", back_populates="reviews", lazy="select")
    likes = relationship("ReviewLike", back_populates="review", lazy="select")


class ReviewLike(Base):
    __tablename__ = "review_like"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    review_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('review.id'), nullable=False)
    like = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.current_timestamp())

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="likes", lazy="select")
    review = relationship("Review", back_populates="likes", lazy="select")

Now all these queries work fine. But I need to put user_like_query and likes_query as a subquery in the query. I can't do it. And how to correctly fetch data from it

Check the docs! It's pretty clear in my opinion.
Just to put you on the right track, you're trying to use ORM entities in the subquery select (ex. select(ReviewLike)) which is a tiny bit more complicated than selecting the individual fields and then joining (ex. select(ReviewLike.review_id, ReviewLike.whatever_else).
In the docs, the example they give automatically figures out the constraint to join on (ex. Review.review_id in your case) but I think it's always better to explicitly specify it then anyone reading your code is clear on what it's doing.
Read this section first (even the fine print!):
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#subqueries-and-ctes
And the code you want to use is in this section:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#orm-entity-subqueries-ctes
If you still need help after this, I think ChatGPT can give you a quick answer. But I really recommend you read through it and do it yourself if you're new to SQLAlchemy. It'll be 10x harder the next time ChatGPT can't help, then you'll have to learn the basics + fix a complex issue.
Underrated skill to read docs these days.

thanks! I absolutely agree with you. Been avoiding them complex sql-queries for too long

I figured, been there done that
One really nice reference book on this btw is Miguel Grinberg's SQLAlchemy book. I pop it open every once in a while when I have some  complex group by to construct and need to refresh my mind on sqlalchemy 2.0 syntax.
